# buff/cache gets filled, how to clear it AZURE VM

Tags: linux, azure, virtual-machine

my RAM got filled completely, and the buff/cache occupied all the memory pl z do let me know how to make it clear when I run the command free -m I get this output,
this is a Linux VM made on azure for WordPress bitnami
**$ free -m
total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           64320       19319        3164         115       41837       44168
Swap:              0**
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRFrT.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I got some buff/cache like below**.

[image]

**To clear the buff/cache try to use the below command.**

Every Linux has three options to clear cache

First - clear page cache only

```
  echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Second - clear dentries and inodes

```
echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Third - clear page cache and dentries and inodes

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

When I try to run this above script, there is 912M of total RAM, and 144M as used. And before I have 352M as free after exciting the script my buff/cache were reduced from 415 to 58 and free Ram increased upto 708M

[image]

***Reference***:

[Clear RAM Memory Cache, Buffer, and Swap Space on Linux](https://hostbillo.com/blog/clear-ram-memory-cache-buffer-and-swap-space-on-linux-hostbillo/)   Credits by ***Arpit-saini***